# Using Laravel socialite with CLI

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

Can socialite authenticate from the CLI without the need to use curl? my purpose is to get data from angellist every two hours and store them in the database. so I thought I can have a scheduler to run every two hours. but I need to be authenticated and I don't want to use curl as socialite has many features already in place.

I love to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Mozilla Persona for user authentication, that way you don't have to worry about which social login the user has/doesn't have.

It's probably easier to set up too, and you don't need an https certificate because the the authentication is happening elsewhere (like social auth).

Here's a link to the setup

[Here's a link to the setup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Persona/Quick_setup)

[Here's a php code example](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid-cookbook/tree/master/php)